# SimpleDateFormat is not Formatting the Date as specified

Tags: java, date

I am trying to get current Date in the format. "yyyy/MM/dd". I have written following code to achieve this.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd", Locale.US);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        String dateStr = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        currentDate=  dateFormat.parse(dateStr);
```

The value of current Date after process is this

`Mon Jun 20 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2016`,

The value of `dateStr` after formatting is `2016/06/20`

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Replace the `/` with `-`?

Comment: And exchange `dd` and `MM`?

Comment: `MM` means month, and `20` is not a valid month in any calendar that I'm aware of. Formatting as year-day-month is *very* weird, if that's what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but its still returning me `Mon Jun 20 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2016, `

Comment: That was a typo, i edited that, I need output in `yyyy/MM/dd` format, but its returning me in this `Mon Jun 20 00:00:00 GMT+05:00 2016`

Comment: @Kirmani88 There is *no way* for that date format to assign *that* string to `dateStr`. Are you printing `currentDate` instead, because that looks like the default format of `java.util.Date`? Remember, `Date` is a value. It doesn't have a *format*.

Comment: I want to compare current date with some other date, that is stored in some database.

Comment: Then do that. Why involve date format in that, if the database column is a date datatype?

Comment: No its also a string, but its formatted in `yyyy/MM/dd`, so i need to convert that in date and compare it with current date .

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been covered *hundreds* of times already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing how it works.

`DateFormat.format` takes a `Date` and converts it to String. It is this string (`dateStr` in your code) that holds the date in the format you want.

`DateFormat.parse` takes a `String` and converts it to `Date`. The `Date` object is a date (more precissely a millisecond), it has no format. If you print the resulting `Date` object, it will be printed using its `toString()` implementation, which shows the `Mon Jun...` string. But that value is not related in any way to the `DateFormat` from which you generated the `Date` instance.

Comment: Thanks, i got the point :)